# Make algorithm text grey and showing just part of it using beamer

Tags: beamer, algorithmicx

I am preparing slides and I want to introduce some algorithm on them, however as it is to long to fit, I decided to represent just the important parts of my algorithm.

So I am wondering if it is possible that I have my algorithm, with a part missing. What I mean is it should look like this:

```
Algorithm 1.
Input: data
Require: some constraings
[1]-[10] //this part for example to be cut out, 
11. if condition
12. do something
13. other stuff
```

So I want a few lines to be cut out, but still shown that they are cut out. And then the following statements in the algorithm need of course to have the according numbering (here starting from 11).

This is how my `.tex` file looks so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\setcounter{ALG@line}{11}
\State \textcolor{grey}{Lines cut out}
\State conditions
\State other stuff
\State $d$: stuff
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the width of the range you want to cut out, you may have to manage some manual spacing of the grayed-out line of text. However, this is fairly straight forward, as the list of items inside an `algorithmic` environment are just that... `\item`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setalgolineno}[1]{\setcounter{ALG@line}{\numexpr#1-1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \item[\rlap{\alglinenumber{1-10}}\phantom{\alglinenumber{10}}] \quad \textcolor{gray}{Lines cut out}
    \setalgolineno{11}
    \State conditions
    \State other stuff
    \State $d$: stuff
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh this is a really nice solution thank you. I didnt know I can define times within my environment. Do you know this from reading the package instructions, or you have some other suggestion where I could teach myself more :D

Comment: HOwever I have another question, if I do this within a loop, it is not considering the indentation of the loop and all following commands as well :S..do you know how I could fix this